# FOSUserBundle Propel

Tags: symfony, propel, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.2

I used the FosUserBundle with Symfony2 (2.2) and the ORM Propel (1.6).

I recently updated my project (sf2.1 => 2.2) and I have FOSUser problem with exception:

```
UserQuery not found
BaseUser not found
```

After some searches around, I discover that the propel command "propel:build" or "propel:model:build" doesn't read the "schema.xml" of the FOSUserBundle.

**My problem is that FOSUserBundle doesn't generate the base Propel classes** ("om" and "map" dirs); I can't find why and how I can fix that!

Comment: Do you use SonataUserBundle as well?

Comment: No, i'm using AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but this trick solves this problem:

1. delete the vendor/friendsofsymfony folder
2. relauch "composer update" command

Now propel find the schema and can generate the base classes.

Thanks to stood https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/215